# C# windows forms textbox wordwrap not working

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

I have a multiline textbox on my Windows Form. I am writing a very long string separated by '\r'. WHen I set wordwrap = true, it wraps off as expected.

BUT when I set wordwrap to false it also wraps off but after a greater length. However, I don't want it to wrap at all.

I have tried changing MaxLength to a huge number - but it makes no difference.

Comment: Try it with RichTextBox Control

Comment: Is it a windows form or an asp.net form?

If windows look into:
// Allow the RETURN key in the TextBox control.
textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
and
// Set WordWrap to true to allow text to wrap to the next line.
textBox1.WordWrap = true;

Comment: Lysgaard: I DON'T want wordwrap

Comment: Cody: That solved my problem. I would accept if you repost it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm (as it wasn't clear as the original commentator's name changed): Switching to a RichTextBox will fix word wrap on really long lines.